# Pushing a new view controller on iOS split view controller

Tags: ios6, xcode4.3, ipad

I am using a splitviewcontroller template. From the detail view I am navigating to a different view controller using a SEGUE. The problem is the new view only displays in the detail view part of the split view. I want the new view to cover entire screen or a way to completely remove master view (when new view is pushed) and push master view back later. How can i do that ?

some code examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this delegate method to conditionally hide the master view:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController (UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return YES;
}
```